# Saving Realm objects on interactive UI

Tags: ios, database, swift, nsoperationqueue, realm

I have a table view and once a cell is about to become visible I load its image. When the image is loaded a model holding its **NSData** (which inherits from **Object**) should be written to a database.

I have tried two ways:

1. Wait until all images are loaded and then write the data to the
   database.
2. Write each loaded image's model to the database.

The first one requires either to scroll through the whole table view (if we load images lazily) or to load images on `viewDidLoad()` which isn't the best choice either. 
The second way is good, as soon as an image is loaded its model eventually updates. But **Realm** freezes the UI on `write()` function.

I've tried to use an asynchronous main queue for writing but this produces short glitches each time Realm performs the write operation. I also tried to use a UserInitiated asynchronous queue but this only caused my app to crash...

```
    let queue = NSOperationQueue()
    queue.qualityOfService = .UserInitiated

    // this code is executed on imageDidLoad()
    queue.addOperationWithBlock {
          let realm = Realm()
          realm.refresh()
          realm.write {
                realm.add(downloadable!, update: true)
          }
    }
```

As a result I'm getting:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object is already persisted in a Realm'

What a solution might be?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without more context, but it appears that `downloadable` is already a persisted `Object`, so trying to use it on another thread won't actually work. If `downloadable` has a primary key, you might want to use that instead, doing something akin to the following:

```
let queue = NSOperationQueue()
queue.qualityOfService = .UserInitiated

let primaryKey = downloadable.primaryKey

// this code is executed on imageDidLoad()
queue.addOperationWithBlock {
      let realm = Realm()
      realm.refresh()
      realm.write {
            realm.create(DownloadableClass.Self, value: ["primaryKey" : primaryKey, "imageData" : imageData], update: true)
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggested way but my model seems to be wrong. How would you save data were you me?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing more about your particular application, but I'd probably store the image data inline with the rest of the object.